# Unable to find function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I created a small test function to try to figure out how I can delete multiple events based on a keyword.

I put two events on 1/24/2014 one named '5D - 1' and one names '5D - 2'

```
function testDelete(){
  var calId = "<id>";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  var date = new Date('1/24/2014/');
  var Events = cal.getEventsForDay(date, {search: '5D'});
  Events.deleteEventSeries();
};
```

But I get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot find function deleteEventSeries in object CalendarEvent,CalendarEvent. (line 36, file "Code")`

And that just doesn't make any sense to me. Why can't it find the function? According to [this reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series) it looks like it should work.

The only thing I can think of is that the object 'CalendarEvent,CalendarEvent' doesn't count as an event (I tried that) or as an event series and I have to delete the events one-by-one.

Comment: does `cal.deleteEventSeries()` help? from the look of it, evens is just a set of events, while cal is the actual calendar which probably has the 'deleteEventSeries()' function

Comment: No, because in that case no events are selected, just the calendar itself.

Comment: are you sure the id of calender is '<id>`? seems a strange name for a calender!

Comment: No, that's not the ID, I changed it just for the purpose of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned object is an array of all the events for this day. If you know there is only one event with that name you can simply use this code:

```
function testDelete(){
  var calId = "h22nevo15tm0nojb6ul4hu7ft8@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  var date = new Date('2/21/2014/');
  var Events = cal.getEventsForDay(date, {search: 'test event'});
  Events[0].deleteEvent();// get first result from the search
};
```

*if you used recurence please let me know, the code would be different...*

EDIT : here is the code for eventSeries and multiple results :

```
function testDeleteSerie(){
  var calId = "h22nevo15tm0nojb6ul4hu7ft8@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  var date = new Date('2/22/2014/');
  var events = cal.getEventsForDay(date, {search: 'test event'});
  for(var n in events){
    var eventId = events[n].getId();
    var eventSerie = cal.getEventSeriesById(eventId);
    eventSerie.deleteEventSeries();
  }
}
```

Note also that there is a nice tool to remove duplicates in calendars (among other things this tool can do ;) that I developed using Romain Vialard Library, feel free to [have a look to it on his webSite](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/calendar/calendar_edit_example)

Comment: The point of this is to possibly remove all the duplicates of an event, so I may have to remove more than one event at a time. If more than one event is returned, how can I delete them all?

Comment: Also, that's kind of what I expected, and I tried your code and it works for a single event, but that's not what I need. And no, there's no recurrence. It's not actually an EventSeries, I was just trying that.

Comment: Do I have to get the length of the array and then create a loop that goes through and deletes the events in the array one by one?

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Also, CalendarAppsExtended doesn't work for me. I already tried it because I have to also find a way to color events but it's not possible without CAE.

Comment: There is no reason it shouldn't work... this spreadsheet/library has been tested a lot of times... did you follow the install instructions ? btw, thx for accepting ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'll see if you can help me fix it in a bit, I'm trying to integrate what we got done here into my script. If we can fix CalendarAppExtended for me that would be a big deal.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're around but I completely finished my script and I want to work out the Calendarapp Extended problem so I created a chatroom. I think this is the link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50336/calendarappextended-troubleshooting